# Create a aggregated matrix using Pandas

Tags: pandas, matrix, aggregate, divide

I have the following `areaId` and `areaNo` information. I am trying to create a matrix with their aggregated values

```
areaId                            areaNo
 a1                                 01
 a1                                 02
 a1                                 02
 b1                                 03   
 b1                                 03
 b2                                 01
 b2                                 03
```

Desired matrix

```
         01      02      03
 a1       1       2       0
 b1       0       0       2 
 b2       1       0       0
```

I was able to get the number of areaIds for each Zone using `groupby`, however I need a matrix.

```
 grouped = df.groupby('areaId')

 df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'areaId': grouped['areaNo'].size().index,
  'nrArea': grouped['areaId'].nunique(),
 })
```

How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pd.crosstab`

```
In [82]: df
Out[82]:
  areaId  areaNo
0     a1       1
1     a1       2
2     a1       2
3     b1       3
4     b1       3
5     b2       1
6     b2       3

In [83]: pd.crosstab(df['areaId'], df['areaNo'])
Out[83]:
areaNo  1  2  3
areaId
a1      1  2  0
b1      0  0  2
b2      1  0  1
```

Or use `pd.pivot_table`

```
In [87]: pd.pivot_table(df, index='areaId', columns='areaNo', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
Out[87]:
areaNo  1  2  3
areaId
a1      1  2  0
b1      0  0  2
b2      1  0  1
```

Or using `groupby` and `unstack`

```
In [88]: df.groupby(['areaId', 'areaNo']).size().unstack('areaNo').fillna(0)
Out[88]:
areaNo    1    2    3
areaId
a1      1.0  2.0  0.0
b1      0.0  0.0  2.0
b2      1.0  0.0  1.0
```